# childNodes[] not working in IE9 as in IE7 and 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have some code that works in IE7 and 8 but not in 9

```
var table = document.getElementById('RadGrid_ctl01').childNodes[2];
```

which doesn't work in IE9, now I did read that IE9 count white spaces etc and therefore the index won't be the same as in IE7 and IE8 so I debugged and found same values when I changed index from 2 to 4 like so:

```
var table = document.getElementById('RadGrid_ctl01').childNodes[4];
```

However when I later on try to access the table object with this code

```
var editor = table.childNodes[i].childNodes[j].childeNodes[0]
```

the variable editor will get the expected value in IE7 and IE8, but in IE9 it becomes null since the childNodes[j] doesn't have any children. I have no idea what causes this.
both i and j starts at 0.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which are you asking about? The `getElementById` issue? Or the accessing by child index issue? And if you have a question about DOM selection, it's pretty tough to answer if we don't know what your markup looks like.

Comment: Yes, I chose a bad title, I will see if I can't supply the markup as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour of IE9 is right, lower versions are wrong.
The problem is caused by whitespace between two html-tags, which should lead into text-nodes.

**UPDATE: Added example**

```
<ul><li>Foo</li><li>Bar</li></ul>

<ul>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
</ul>
```

Looks pretty much the same, doesn't it? However the resulting DOM differs.
First example would result in:

```
- ul
-- li
--- (text)Foo
-- li
---(text)Bar
```

While the second Markup leads into this:

```
- ul
-- (text)
-- li
--- (text)Foo
-- (text)
-- li
--- (text)Bar
-- (text)
```

And since text-nodes cannot have any child-nodes, this causes your Javascript to fail silently.

**Possible solution**

One solution is to strip out the empty text-nodes. I once wrote a [gist](https://gist.github.com/1UnitedPower/4072004) for this issue.

**UPDATE:**

[`Node.normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.normalize) seems to be a more reliable solution, but i didn't check it for browser-compatibilty.

Comment: Worked like a charm! very much appreciated.