# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByTagName' in IE9

Tags: javascript, asp.net, treeview

I've a page with a TreeView control and the parent node is checked, the child nodes will be checked as well. It was done using javascript. But when the page is opened is IE9 and trying to check the parent node, I will get an error of:

**Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByTagName'**

```
function AreAllSiblingsChecked(chkBox)
{
 var parentDiv = GetParentByTagName("div", chkBox);
 var childCount = parentDiv.childNodes.length;
 for(var i=0;i<childCount;i++)
 {
             var prevChkBox = parentDiv.childNodes[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
             //if any of sibling nodes are not checked, return false
             if(prevChkBox.checked)
             {
                return true;
             }
 }
 return false;
}

//utility function to get the container of an element by tagname
function GetParentByTagName(parentTagName, childElementObj)
{
 var parent = childElementObj.parentNode;
 while(parent.tagName.toLowerCase() != parentTagName.toLowerCase())
     {
         parent = parent.parentNode;
     }
 return parent;
}
```

Appreciate if someone can help me to solve this! thanks in advance...

Comment: I'm assuming this works in other browsers?

Comment: yes. It works fine in IE8.

Comment: Do you have somewhere where you can reproduce the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE9, childNodes[] returns text nodes (comments or whitespace) as well as child tags.  Text nodes do not support getElementsByTagName().  There's a good summary of the underlying DOM model [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900805/childnodes-not-working-in-ie9-as-in-ie7-and-8).

The easiest fix is just to check for the existence of the method before using it:

```
function AreAllSiblingsChecked(chkBox)
{
     var parentDiv = GetParentByTagName("div", chkBox);
     var childCount = parentDiv.childNodes.length;
     for(var i=0;i<childCount;i++)
     {
         if (parentDiv.childNodes[i].getElementsByTagName) {
             var prevChkBox = parentDiv.childNodes[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
             //if any of sibling nodes are not checked, return false
             if(prevChkBox.checked)
             {
                return true;
             }
         }
     }
     return false;
}
```