# Code works on firefox but not IE

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer, firefox

So first im loading an XML file. Then looping through it to find the data.

```
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("number");
var l = x.length;                       
for (i=0;i<l;i++){
    if (x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue == strTeam) {                              

        document.write("<center>Scouting Data For: " + x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</center></br>");                    
        var xmlDoc1 = loadXMLString(teamXML2);
```

The code keeps looping find until I enter the if statement. Once the If statement finishes and the loop continues I get an error.

`SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'childNodes' of undefined or null reference`

on this line of code

`if (x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue == strTeam)`

Also if this helps I must use IE because there is no other browser on a Windows Surface RT. But I ran the code on my desktop in Firefox and chrome and it ran with no errors. Any help?

---

So just an edit here,

If I remove `var l = x.length` and replace `i<l` with `i<x.length` I get an `Access is Denied` error on this line of code `for (i=0;i<l;i++){`

Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

[childNodes[] not working in IE9 as in IE7 and 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900805/childnodes-not-working-in-ie9-as-in-ie7-and-8)

Does your html have any code that leads to whitespace between two html-tags, which should lead into text-nodes?

Comment: No I don't have whitespaces. Take a look at my edit with the new error. Strange