# Why does appendChild(Text) on IE11 fail?

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-11

The second `appendChild()` below fails in IE11 (and possibly others):

```js
var span = document.getElementById('domNode');
var existingTextNode = span.childNodes[0];
span.innerHTML = '';

var newTextNode = document.createTextNode('new Text Node');
console.log(existingTextNode.nodeName, "=?=", newTextNode.nodeName);

span.appendChild(newTextNode);
console.log('newTextNode appended OK');

span.appendChild(existingTextNode);
console.log('existingTextNode appended OK');
```

```html
<span id='domNode'>pre-existing Text Node</span>
```

The new `TextNode` gets appended successfully. The existing one fails:

```
Error: {
  "message": "Invalid argument.",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 23,
  "colno": 1
}
```

What's the underlying reason for the failure here? (Is this defined behavior? A bug?) Is it specific to pre-existing `TextNode` objects?

... And most importantly, is my only workaround to just always create new `TextNode`'s when I need to append them? Or, is there some trick I'm missing that will allow me to treat a pre-existing `TextNode` like any other node?

Comment: are you trying to move the existing text node or copy it?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. copy would be OK -- and it's not too terribly difficult to put in special handling for that. the underlying concern is that this is *really* unexpected behavior (to me). i want to understand if this behavior is defined somewhere -- or if it's a known bug. and in either case, how deep and broad the surprises go ...

Comment: yea, appears to be an IE bug in certain versions of IE. google "IE childNodes" and you'll see a few other threads about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [childNodes\[\] not working in IE9 as in IE7 and 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900805/childnodes-not-working-in-ie9-as-in-ie7-and-8)

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. As far as I can tell, the problem is not occurring when I try to access `childNodes`; it's only occurring when I attempt to append a child that previously lived in the DOM. I'm not referring to it in a collection at that point, I've grabbed it with a variable... I'll need to verify that later and update the question.